# I just installed a 14.04 32 bit update, and now I get no Video using N-Vidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, updates, video

I just performed a suggested update by the Update Manager on Ubuntu 14.04, and now I get no video when I reboot.

I get the splash screen, then it goes black.

Can I somehow switch back to default X drivers from terminal?

Comment: Using Laptop or Desktop ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today, here's what helped me:

1. Boot into [recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and get into root shell ([screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaeNP.jpg)).
2. Make root partition writable: `mount -o remount rw /`
3. Remove all nvidia packages: `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`
4. Reboot into normal mode: `reboot`

Now you are using open source Nouveau driver. If you wish, you can [reenable Nvidia binary driver](https://askubuntu.com/a/201524/66674).

Comment: This is exactly what I did, by putting a few other posts from various locations together.  I do appreciate the response!  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Reboot and enter into recovery mode By Pressing SHIFT Key

After reaching the menu choose drop to shell

Then execute the command

```
sudo mount -o remount rw /
```

Edit the file

```
# sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

And modify the line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

It to obtain this line :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=noirq acpi=force apm=power_off quiet splash"
```

Then, save, close, and back in the terminal, execute :

```
# sudo update-grub
```

Now, when you will Shutdown, it should Work great.